# Manually triggering the ttk notebook tab change event

Tags: python, events, tabs, tkinter, ttk

I'm talking about `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` event that `ttk.Notebook` can be bound to. Say I have:

```
def tabChanged(self, event):
    print "tab changed"
```

And say I want to manually trigger this method. What I actually mean by this is, say I have a basic, tabbed GUI and there's a start button which makes plots when you click it. There are plots on each tab and when you change tabs, `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` is triggered, which is an automatically created event by `ttk.Notebook`. I already have a `self.tabChanged` method for this case. What I wanna do is, I wanna make my start button trigger this event so I don't have to create a new method just for the button which will do the exact same thing as `self.tabChanged`. So I need a way of triggering the event through a button click, but remember, that event is `ttk.Notebook`'s own event and apparently it was designed to be used with tabs, not buttons. Is there a way to trigger `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` manually with a button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate virtual events (eg: events that begin and end with `<<` and `>>`) with [event_generate](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.event_generate-method):

```
self.the_notebook.event_generate("<<NotebookTabChanged>>")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Generating the virtual event via this line added after the last line of my button click method gave me the results I wanted.